# Why is Thrift Binary protocol serialization so much slow?

Tags: python, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm newbie on thrift. I wrote a thrift server in python, also client in python too.

## Here is my thrift defination:

```
struct RatingByReport {
    1: required string ticker,
    2: required i32 cnt_institution,
    3: optional list<string> strong_buy,
    4: optional list<string> buy,
    5: optional list<string> neutral,
    6: optional list<string> sell,
    7: optional list<string> strong_sell,
    8: optional i32 cnt_maintain,
    9: optional i32 cnt_upgrade,
    10: optional i32 cnt_downgrade,
    11: optional i32 avg_score,
    12: optional string adjustment
}

struct TableRatingByReport {
    1: required list<string> head,
    2: required list<RatingByReport> body,
    3: optional struct.CadaTranslation translation
}



service china{
    void ping(),
    TableRatingByReport rating_byreport(1:string ticker) throws (1:struct.CadaInternalError error)
}
```

## Here is my server side:

```
handler = StockChinaHandler()
processor = china.Processor(handler)
#startup()

transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=30303)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
#server = TProcessPoolServer.TProcessPoolServer(processor, transport,
#        tfactory, pfactory)

print "Start server..."
import cProfile
print >>open('/tmp/test.log', 'w'), cProfile.run('server.serve()',
        sort='cumulative')
#server.serve()
print "done!"
```

## Client side:

```
# Make socket
transport = TSocket.TSocket('localhost', 30303)

# Buffering is critical. Raw sockets are very slow
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)

# Wrap in a protocol
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)

# Create a client to use the protocol encoder
client = china.Client(protocol)

# Connect!
transport.open()

client.ping()
print "ping()"

print msg
msg = client.rating_byreport('2012-01-04')
print msg
transport.close()
```

## cProfile result:

```
       ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  230.968  230.968 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000  230.968  230.968 TServer.py:74(serve)
        3    0.000    0.000  225.967   75.322 TSocket.py:172(accept)
        3    0.000    0.000  225.967   75.322 socket.py:194(accept)
        3  225.967   75.322  225.967   75.322 {method 'accept' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        5    0.003    0.001    4.993    0.999 china.py:140(process)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.200    3.200 china.py:177(process_rating_byreport)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.366    2.366 china.py:500(write)
        1    0.003    0.003    2.366    2.366 ttypes.py:515(write)
     1455    0.261    0.000    2.363    0.002 ttypes.py:364(write)
   155556    0.246    0.000    1.995    0.000 TCompactProtocol.py:38(nested)
   145880    0.298    0.000    1.640    0.000 TCompactProtocol.py:255(__writeString)
       18    1.370    0.076    1.370    0.076 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    1.292    0.258 TCompactProtocol.py:306(readMessageBegin)
       13    0.000    0.000    1.292    0.099 TCompactProtocol.py:286(__readUByte)
       26    0.000    0.000    1.291    0.050 TTransport.py:54(readAll)
       26    0.000    0.000    1.291    0.050 TTransport.py:154(read)
        5    0.000    0.000    1.291    0.258 TSocket.py:101(read)
```

In my case, TableRatingByReport instance got a body with 1400 rows(list\), and It cost over 3 seconds(function *process_rating_byreport*, which is auto generate by thift) to generate binnary content. I don't know why it is so slow.

Using json to serialize the same data, It's only spend less than 200 ms.

I'm wondering did I use the uncorrect way to manipulate thrift?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use TBinaryProtocolAccelerated if speed is important. It is implemented in C and is about 10x faster than Python implementation of TBinaryProtocol.

Also, in your benchmark are comparing raw JSON parsing to full Thrift parsing, which is not a fair comparison. Try creating all the Thrift objects from the parsed JSON to see whether the overhead comes from parsing or instantiating so many PyObjects.

Regardless, if you care about parsing performance and JSON is sufficient for your application (i.e. you use no binary data, you don't want a nice RPC interface, etc) then you should use it.